# Calculating Cohen's d from standardized or unstandardized regression coefficients (GLM/GLMM) for meta-analysis

Tags: generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients, cohens-d

I am currently conducting a meta-analysis about the effect of blood parasites on different fitness parameters of song birds.
Since I have a rather large number of parameters that I want to incorporate, I decided to use a standardised effect size (Cohen's d). Whenever possible I am using the mean+SE or SD of the two different groups (infected/not infected) to calculate Cohens d, but there are a handful of studies that only report standardised or unstandardised regression coefficients (deriving from a GLM or GLMM) together with standard errors and sample sizes.

I am now wondering if I could use those coefficients to calculate Cohen's d by using the esc_beta / esc_B function in R. I am not sure if the outcome is accurate enough for it to be used and couldn't find any literature on this.
I'd be very grateful for any kind of input!

Comment: If they regressed group membership on fitness then that would be an estimate of the mean difference conditional on the covariates. Be careful though as if they have adjusted for different covariates the regression coefficients are not estimating the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Covariates indeed differ between studies (common are covariates such as age, sex, arrival date, host species, breeding site etc). So since they influence the estimate, the use of different covariates makes a comparison obsolete?

Comment: I think it would be difficult to justify but it would be up to you to argue the case. I would recommend doing a meta-regression with a categorical predictor for d versus regression. If there are several with the same set of covariates you could add more categories to it for each group to see if, empirically, there is a difference.