# How to transform GEE coefficients to Cohen's d (standardized mean difference) for meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, generalized-estimating-equations, cohens-d, standardized-mean-difference

I am conducting a meta analysis and am looking into how to convert coefficients (with SEs) from a GEE linear estimation into a standardized mean difference, Cohen's d. Does anyone have any hints on whether and how this might be possible?

I found a similar question here but no response:
[Calculating Cohen's d from standardized or unstandardized regression coefficients (GLM/GLMM) for meta-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/599531/calculating-cohens-d-from-standardized-or-unstandardized-regression-coefficient)

Comment: Can you provide details on _standardized mean difference, Cohen's d_ ? To me they sound two different things.

Comment: Meta analysis does not use Cohen's $d$.  That would cause point estimates of effects to be enlarged for some studies just because of their standard deviations, even though the means are the same.

Comment: Is the independent variable binary?

Comment: Yes, it is an RCT paper, so the independent variable is the treatment dummy. The dependent variable is also binary.